# "Call" a specific function from device driver's C code

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux

If I had written code in C for a device driver that could control the GPIO on a RPI, how would I be able to actually call a function from my C code such as `ssize_t mygpio_write(struct file *filep, const char __user *ubuf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)` to turn on an LED for instance?

I know that I can/have to

- Execute a Makefile on the C file
- Use `insmod` to insert a module such as "name.ko"
- I can read from the module with `cat /dev/name`
- Use `rmmod` to remove a module such as "name.ko"

But other than that, I am unaware of how to give the driver certain "parameters" so that I can for instance control the GPIO on a RPI.

As an extra note: I do also know what major and minor numbers are, but I am unaware about whether or not, I have to use them to call a function from the code or control the GPIO.

Comment: This is probably too broad a topic for SO. Suggest you read up on [linux kernel led subsytem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/leds/leds-class.txt). There is a well defined way to expose leds to user land.

Comment: @kaylum
I don't mean the LED on the raspberry pi. I mean LEDS connected to the GPIO pins.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/ not helping?
I am not an expert in Linux drivers, but I think ioctl is the way to access driver functions. Assign arbitrary numbers to custom services, and call them from user space.

Comment: For LEDs there is LED subsystem with it's own ABI, for many other things as well. Simple GPIO use can be done with `libgpiod` tools.